How can I find the angle between curve segments?
I'm trying to figure out how to do it, I only neeed the angle from the X-Y axis between one segment and the next one. I checked out some other similar questions, but none of the ones I found were about curve segments.

When I ask to chat GPT it gives me this formula, and I interpret it like that. The problem is the results don't seem accurate at all. But I feel that would be the way to go. The only thing in this example is that I haven't considered only the X-Y axis.


Do you need the signed or unsigned angle here, and is your curve in 2D or 3D?

You can use the Offset Point in Curve node to sample the position of the points +1 / -1 from the current point, then getting the vectors to each using subtraction.
We can then flatten the vectors to only be on the XY plane my multiplying with a vector of (1, 1, 0) which removes the Z component.
Finally we can calculate the angle between two arbitrary vectors using the final group of nodes. This final group will work on any vectors in any direction to each other, but because we first flattened the Z component then we are only getting the angle on the plane.

The final angle calculation does use the same formula that ChatGPT gave you, but if we normalize the vectors we can omit the denominator because it is just 1.

Oh that's it, thanks very much! And I noticed that apparently I was using the wrong node, there is an 'arcsine' and an 'arccosine'...
